# From VB6 checking if date exist in holiday table in access

Tags: sql, arrays, vba, date, ms-access

Below is a function that I'm currently using to subtract 20 days from an invoice date and then to move that date to Monday if it falls on a weekend.  The next step is to check if that date is in the Holiday table and if it is adjust the date accordingly.  The issue is I'm running this check against 30K plus records and it's taking to long.  Is there a faster method to accomplish this same task?  Thanks in advance.

```
Public Function PrintDate(TheDate As Date) As Date
   Dim OfficeClosed         As Integer
   Dim CheckDate            As Date
   Dim QSDate               As String
   Dim QS                   As String

OfficeClosed = False

TheDate = DateAdd("d", -20, TheDate)

            Select Case Weekday(TheDate)
            Case 1
                CheckDate = DateAdd("d", 1, TheDate)
            Case 7
                CheckDate = DateAdd("d", 2, TheDate)
            Case Else
                CheckDate = TheDate
        End Select

QSDate = CheckDate

QS = ""
QS = QS & "SELECT holidaydate "
QS = QS & "FROM tbl_holidays "


Set ado_objConn = New ADODB.Connection

ado_objConn.ConnectionTimeout = 130
ado_objConn.CommandTimeout = 130

ado_objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & _
    gl_AutoFinance_Data_Loc & "';Persist Security Info=False"

ado_objConn.Open
Set ado_objRs8 = New ADODB.Recordset
ado_objRs8.Open QS, ado_objConn, , , adCmdText
    With ado_objRs8
         If Not .EOF Then
            .MoveFirst
             While Not .EOF

                        If ado_objRs8.Fields(0) = QSDate Then
                           OfficeClosed = True
                        End If
            .MoveNext
            Wend
        End If

   End With

Set ado_objRs8 = Nothing
Set ado_objConn = Nothing

If OfficeClosed = True Then
        Select Case Weekday(CheckDate)
            Case 2
                PrintDate = DateAdd("d", 1, CheckDate)
            Case 3
                PrintDate = DateAdd("d", 1, CheckDate)
            Case 4
                PrintDate = DateAdd("d", 1, CheckDate)
            Case 5
                PrintDate = DateAdd("d", 1, CheckDate)
            Case 6
                PrintDate = DateAdd("d", 3, CheckDate)
        End Select
Else
PrintDate = CheckDate
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include a condition in from clause:

```
QS = ""
QS = QS & "SELECT holidaydate "
QS = QS & "FROM tbl_holidays "
QS = QS & "Where holidaydate = #" & QSDate & "#"
```

If the recordset returns some record, then OfficeClosed = True. You must delete the condition in loop, this way you do not have to go through the recordset